# How do you create a Plasitc SCM Repo from an existing project?

Tags: plasticscm

I have an existing unity project for which I want to make a Plastic SCM repo. The only options I see in the windows plastic scm project are "Create New Repository" and "Create Workspace From a Repository". How do I create a Repository from an existing set of local files?

Comment: Would you not be able to create a new repo using the program and then copy and paste what you have into there? Then just push what you have to the main branch and work from there with small edits to what you need to do in the project? For my Unity projects, I use Git and GitHub to save my repos. I just work from that local repo and when it is time to push to the main branch of the GitHub repo, I send it from there. Saves me time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You will need to create a new repository (database stored on the server-side to store the repo history).
2. Then you create a local workspace in your project local path pointing to the repo you just created.
3. Finally, you can checkin your initial version of the project to the repository.